# Cucumber.js and resources

Tags: javascript, cucumberjs

I  hope I don't get dinged for this - but I am starting Cucumber.js and javascript testing and the tutorials/docs I have seen leave me wanting.

I've searched on amazon, but the books seemed more geared towards Ruby - curious if these books would still be a wealth of positive info for those using cucumber.js for javascript?

The Cucumber Book: Behaviour-Driven Development for Testers and Developers

Cucumber Recipes: Automate Anything with BDD Tools and Techniques

Instant Cucumber BDD How-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this as a good starting point. It has instructions and offered cucumber.js steps. You can simply include it along with cucumber.js. Follow the instructions and it should work.

https://github.com/AllegiantAir/cucumber-defaults

Answer (score 0):

There is a BDD Web Automation blogs series you may want to take a look:

[BDD Web Automation 01: Create and Run the First Sample](https://www.codementor.io/cuketest/bdd-automation-01-create-and-run-the-first-sample-muy8htpqy)

Also here is a Cucumber.js authoring tool that may guide you through creating a Cucumber.js automation script.

[CukeTest Overview](http://cuketest.com/en/)